# How do I use JQuery's parseXML to parse from escaped string to an XML Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have a very large XML file that is escaped with `&lt; &gt; &quot;` etc.
I tested the XML and verified that it's well formed. I suspect there is some issue with unescaping the XML reserved characters.

Example: `&lt;` to "<"

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
xml_string = “&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;&lt;root&gt;&lt;test&gt;&lt;/test&gt;&lt;/root&gt”;
xml_object = $.parseXML(unescape(xml_string));
```

I constantly get "Invalid XML" errors from parseXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unescape() function isn't going to work in this context. Instead you can use the decode() function in my answer below. This is old but tried and true. Basically by assigning the value to a ghost element we can "escape" it there.

```js
var xml_string = '&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;&lt;root&gt;&lt;test&gt;&lt;/test&gt;&lt;/root&gt';


function decode(input) {
  var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
  txt.innerHTML = input;
  return txt.value;
}

var decodedString = decode(xml_string);
console.log('Decoded: ', decodedString);

var xml_object = $.parseXML(decodedString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I found this solution online and I'm wondering if it could cause an out of memory issue if the xml_string is too large? I'm working with 80mb files and the larger ones never load. I'm trying to figure out where the issue would be in the code, and the profiler shows the decode function running a long time. It's that or the parseXML call.

Comment: I mean if you are working with 80mb xml files, you need to explore working on this in your backend. Anything 80mb in a browser is going to cause problems.